# Calling fields in added set in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to add a field from a model called `BlockContent` to `Block`.

```
    block_list = Block.objects.filter(lesson=int(num))

    # For each block, fill the stuff inside of the latest revision:
    for block in block_list:
        additional = BlockContent.objects.filter(block=block.id).latest('id')
        block.blockcontent_set.add(additional)
        print("check: ", block.content)
```

This keeps throwing

```
'Block' object has no attribute 'content'
```

I'd guess it has to do with the how I'm calling the model, but I can't seem to get my head around it. I've tried a few different combos (e.g. `block.blockcontent_set.content` and `block.blockcontent.content`) without any luck.

Purpose: Trying to get this into an easy-to-use variable to pass into a for-loop in a template.

---

```
class Block(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey('Lesson')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class BlockContent(models.Model):
    block = models.ForeignKey('Block')
    content = models.TextField()
    type = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    revision = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    latest = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Comment: I think the problem is your check `print("check: ", block.content)`. Try printing `block.blockcontent_set.all()` or some such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In current models, there are a Many-To-One relation between your `Block` model class and `BlockContent` model class, Change your code to resolve bug:

```
block_list = Block.objects.filter(lesson=int(num))

# For each block, fill the stuff inside of the latest revision:
for block in block_list:
    additional = BlockContent.objects.filter(block=block.id).latest('id')
    block.blockcontent_set.add(additional)
    # The block.blockcontent_set contains multiple BlockContent objects
    for block_content in block.blockcontent_set.all():
        print("check: ", block_content.content)
```

Also if you want to have One-To-One relation between `Block` and `BlockContent` change The type of `block` attribute in `BlockContent` class to `OneToOneField`:

```
class BlockContent(models.Model):
    block = models.OneToOneField('Block')
    content = models.TextField()
    type = models.IntegerField(default=1)
    revision = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    latest = models.BooleanField(default=True)
```

Then you must use `blockcontent` instead of `blockcontent_set` in using of `block` objects.

If you want a way to use the `content` attribute of `BlockContent` class in `Block` class in brief, you can add a property to the `Block` class, similar below:

```
class Block(models.Model):
    lesson = models.ForeignKey('Lesson')
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    @property
    def contents(self):
        return [bc.content for bc in self.blockcontents_set.all()]
```

Then you can using:

```
{% for content in block.contents %}
    <span>{{ content }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Instead of:

```
{% for bc in block.blockcontent_set.all %}
    <span>{{ bc.content }}</span>
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use `related_field` in `BlockContent` model while declaring `Block` as `ForeignKey`:

```
block = models.ForeignKey('Block', related_name='related_content')
```

Then you can use this related name to access records of `BlockContent` from `Block` object.

So, your code will be:

```
block_list = Block.objects.filter(lesson=int(num))

for block in block_list:
    block.related_content.all()  # related_content is the related_name
```